# How to get columns from an org.apache.spark.sql row by name?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have reading records from a kafka source to `mydataframe` spark dataframe.
I want to pick some column from the `row` and do some operation. So to check if I am getting the correct index, I tried to print the index in the statement `println(row.getFieldIndex(pathtoDesiredColumnFromSchema))` as shown below:

```
val pathtoDesiredColumnFromSchema = "data.root.column1.column2.field"
val myQuery = mydataframe.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row]() {

  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = true
  override def process(row: Row): Unit = {
    println(row.getFieldIndex(pathtoDesiredColumnFromSchema))
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
}).outputMode("append").start()
```

But the above code says that row has only one name as `data`, and there is no column name `data.root.column1.column2.field`.

What is the correct way to get columns values from the spark sql row by name paths?

Comment: Did you try row.getAs("columnName")?

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakd do you mean like row.getAs("data.root.column1.column2.field")? or just row.getAs("field")?

Comment: row.getAs("field")

Comment: `row.getAs[String]("column_name")` should get you (a casted to scala String version of) the value

Answer (score 4):

You may use chain of `getAs` invocations for `struct` types, for example:

```
val df = spark.range(1,5).toDF.withColumn("time", current_timestamp())
.union(spark.range(5,10).toDF.withColumn("time", current_timestamp()))
.groupBy(window($"time", "1 millisecond")).count


df.printSchema
root
 |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)

df.take(1).head
          .getAs[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]("window")
          .getAs[java.sql.Timestamp]("start")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to print the field of a `DataFrame` you can use

```
mydataframe.select(pathtoDesiredColumnFromSchema).foreach(println(_.get(0)))
```